# What is $e^{\log z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the natural logarithm log e is the inverse of the exponential function e.More concretely it is:
$\log(e^z)=z+2ik\pi$
But what is precisely $\exp (\log z$)?

Comment: A set of elements :)

Comment: @ZelosMalum: are you sure ?

Comment: a singleton set, that is

Answer (score 9):

It's always the case that $e^{\log z} = z$, since any two branches of the logarithm differ by $2n\pi i$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $e^{2n\pi i} = 1$.

More specifically, for some choice of range of argument, we have $\log z = \log |z| + i\arg z$, and so
$$e^{\log z} = e^{\log|z|+i\arg z} = |z|e^{i\arg z} = z$$